# How to set text-align center all tables in ag-grid

Tags: javascript, ag-grid

I have a question.

I use ag-grid in vue3.

There are several tables in each page and all tables share commonOption object.

```js
const commonOptions = {
  option: {
    pagination: true,
    suppressCellFocus: true,
  },
  columnTypes: {
    dateYmdColumn: {
      valueFormatter: ({ value }) => value.ymd(),
    },
  }
  ...
}
```

```html
<AgGridVue :grid-options="commonOptions" />
```

---

I want to change text-align left(default) to center in all tables **using commonOption object**.

I can change it like this but need to change all table's code in each pages. I think it is inefficient way.

```js
// table1 data in user.vue
columnDefs: [
  {headerName: 'age', cellStyle: {textAlign: 'center'}},
  {headerName: 'name', cellStyle: {textAlign: 'center'}}
  ...
]
```

I read document but can't find answer.
(Usually the answer is change css or add cellStyle in each table's columnDefs.)

Is there any way to set default text-align property?

Thanks in advance for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple solution to your issue:

```
headerNames = ['age', 'name'];
cellStyles = {textAlign: 'center'};
columnDefs = headerNames.map(headerName => ({ headerName, cellStyle: cellStyles }));
```

Besides CSS, I do not know of a way that you could text-align everything at once. Hope this helps!